# Advice for implementing multiple question with multiple choice app on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying to make a exercising app.

After the user creates his account the app should ask couple questions to provide the appropriate exercising program for the user.

I have my questions ready in `QuestionHandler.sharedInstance.questions` And each question has `title:String`and `choices:[String]`

Questions can have different count of choices

My question is, should I make a new view controller for each question or there is a cleaner way of doing this?

Explanation for asking this: each choice should have its own view that has two subviews `ImageView` and `UIButton` (Imagine this as a button with a choice’ And I am really frustrated with how to implement this.

Update:

I need a way without the need for a `UITableViewController`.

Like this image below but this app i found from app store will adapt how many buttons it will generate from the count of the question (describes exactly what i want)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define how many 'types' of questions you have. i.e. how many type of screens you need to show all your questions.

So, if we consider the image you have attached as an example, you see a screen with 
 1. simple buttons (only text) 
 2. large image and custom arrangement of buttons
 3. fancy buttons (multiple text options with an icon)

Irrespective of how many total questions there are there should definitely be a limited number of such 'types'.

Your data model needs to specify the type, and data model for answers within a questions should be able to provide all information required for the 'type' of view you need to show for this specific question.

```
enum QuestionType {
    case simple
    case fancy
    case custom
}

struct Question {
    var questionTitle: String
    var type: QuestionType = .simple
    var choices: [Answer]
    var backgroundImage: UIImage?
}

protocol Answer {
    var answerText: String { get }
}

struct SimpleAnswer: Answer {
    var answerText: String
}

struct FancyAnswer: Answer {
    var answerText: String
    var descriptionText: String
    var icon: UIImage
}

struct CustomAnswer: Answer {
    var answerText: String
    var position: CGPoint
}
```

Of course based on the kind of architecture you follow you should probably split the data model to separate domain details from UI etc. but above code is just an example.

Once you are able to list out these types, you basically need to create a those many view controllers, You can then create and add these view controllers to a [page view controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) or navigation stack, and done.

I am not sure why you do not want to use a table view controller. Once you define these different types, a table view controller will be a perfect fit in come cases.

Comment: your answer makes more sense to me to be honest. my concern with UITableViews is that you can't move cells around they have to be stacked

Comment: and just one more questions do you think I need to use storyboard for creating the views or they need to be coded ?, sorry for these detailed questions but i am trying to see how other senior devs think and try make sense out of it

Comment: You can create a separate storyboard with each of these (one per type) view controllers, and instantiate them from the storyboard. You can drive table / collection view controllers off of the data via datasources, but, you will need to code the custom view with buttons at various positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have

1 QuestionsTableViewController, it would list all of the questions.

1 QuestionChoicesTableViewController, it would list all of the choices of current question.
( if these two viewcontroller have similar UI you can just use one ViewController for it and reload the table view with some animations)

1 QuestionChoiceDetailsViewController, it would show the details of the choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am searching for a way that looks neat without the need for UITableViewController

Comment: What is not neat in UITableViewController?

Comment: Also the image you added now in your question, you can choose collectionviewcontroller to implement it. Otherwise kindly add an explanation what do you mean by “neat”.

Comment: brother i am not trying to take away anything good from your solution, but what i mean by neat is generating the buttons on screen depending on how many choices the question has

Comment: You can generate tableviewcell based on the number of choices, and have the button in it so again please help me understand what do you really want.

Comment: Can't you use a UIStackView ?

Comment: you need to tell us what kind of different UIs you will have for each questions. For example the above example gif, you can use either stackview or tableview inside a view controller for first two choices. And for the third one you can still use stackview with some different layout, so essentially you can still use the same stackview with different layout.

All in all you just use one view controller and updates its content and push it again.